# Trying to call an external api with aws lamda returning error type object

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

This is my code in which i am trying to call an external api with aws lambda.

```
const http = require('http');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let dataString = '';
    const options = {
      host: 'host',
      path: '/v1/endpoint',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };    
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.on('data', chunk => {
            dataString += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            resolve({
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(dataString), null, 4)
            });
          });
        });
        
        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject({
              statusCode: 500,
              body: 'Something went wrong!'
          });
        });
    });
    
    return JSON.stringify(response);
};
```

But what I am getting in response is as follows.

> Test Event Name test1
>
> Response {   "errorType": "object",   "errorMessage": "[object
> Object]",   "trace": [] }
>
> Function Logs START RequestId: c9701afa-9bc5-4750-8e10-5558d5e3e342
> Version: $LATEST
> 2022-03-03T07:23:07.844Z  c9701afa-9bc5-4750-8e10-5558d5e3e342    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"[object
> Object]","stack":["Error: [object Object]","    at _homogeneousError
> (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:12:12)","    at postError
> (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:29:54)","    at done
> (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:58:7)","    at fail
> (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:70:7)","    at
> /var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:106:16","    at
> processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"]}
> END RequestId: c9701afa-9bc5-4750-8e10-5558d5e3e342 REPORT RequestId:
> c9701afa-9bc5-4750-8e10-5558d5e3e342  Duration: 198.36 ms Billed
> Duration: 199 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 57 MB  Init
> Duration: 156.11 ms
>
> Request ID c9701afa-9bc5-4750-8e10-5558d5e3e342

How do i debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Pass your "reject" error object to `JSON.stringify` and the nested error message object will be readable instead of just being [object Object] in the response.

I also suggest passing the actual error object along in the `body`, so that you can see from the response what has gone wrong:

```js
 req.on('error', (e) => {
     reject(JSON.stringify({
         statusCode: 500,
         body: 'Something went wrong: ' + e
     }));
 });
```